# Why aren't there werewolves anymore in the Third Age?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-silmarillion

Who was the responsible for their disappearance? Are they hidden to the South maybe?

Comment: [Gandalf mentioned the werewolves as being among Sauron's servants in the late Third Age](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Werewolves)

Comment: [Here's another question on this site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28405/what-were-the-wolves-that-attacked-the-fellowship-of-the-ring), the answers to which indicate that the Fellowship was attacked by werewolves

Comment: Most of Morgoth's minions were destroyed or went into hiding after the War of Wrath, so if we don't see them, it's not a surprise.

Comment: Good question, but the duplicate answers states that there are werewolves in the west and the east.

Answer (score 4):

**There are werewolves in the Third Age.**

In *The Fellowship of the Ring* Book II, Chapter 1, "Many Meetings" Gandalf tells Frodo that the horses of the Black Riders are bred in Mordor by followers of Sauron the Dark Lord.

> Not all his servants and chattels are wraiths! There are orcs and trolls, there are wargs and **werewolves**; and there have been and still are many Men, warriors and kings, that walk alive under the Sun, and yet are under his sway.  And their number is growing daily.

In *The Fellowship of the Ring* Book II, Chapter 4, "A Journey in the Dark" the Fellowship of the Ring is attacked by what seem to be wargs, but which they later suspect to be more supernatural than wargs are, and thus werewolves.

[What were the wolves that attacked the Fellowship of the Ring?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28405/what-were-the-wolves-that-attacked-the-fellowship-of-the-ring)[1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28405/what-were-the-wolves-that-attacked-the-fellowship-of-the-ring)